# Find all manually installed Ruby Gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I found [this script](https://gist.github.com/915271) that find all manually installed packages in Fedora (every argument that I passed `yum install`). Specifically, the script does not return dependencies that were automatically installed. Is there something similar for Ruby Gems?

Otherwise, does Ruby Gems keep a command history somewhere?

Comment: I'm curious, what would you need this for?

Comment: So that when I reinstall my operating system, I can quickly get the tools I need, and get back to work.

Comment: If you mean gem dependencies of your scripts, then you should use bundler for that.

Comment: Why are you worried if they were installed as a dependency or not? Why not just explicitly reinstall all the gems that were installed on the system before you reinstalled your OS?

Comment: Are you using RVM? Why not maintain a [`global.gems`](https://rvm.io/gemsets/initial/) file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If YUM works like APT (which I assume it does based on your description), it recognizes a difference between explicitly installed packages ("manually" as you say) and implicitly installed ones (i.e. as a dependency).

Rubygems has no such distinction, and thus this is not possible. As mentioned in the comments, Bundler can do this, but that's on a project level more than a system level.

Answer (score 0):

```
history | grep "gem install"
```

This will show all the gem install commands you have used in the computer where you run it.